# Data not showing in the strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an issue with my controller. Data from my table is not showing in my strongly typed view. but when I `return View(CanaClie0012.toList())`; I can see my data perfectly. Im not getting any error. can someone tell me what im doing wrong.

**My Table Model:**

```
public partial class CanaClie0012
{
    public string Client00130012 { get; set; }
    public string F1Pais00200012 { get; set; }
    public string F1Cana02530012 { get; set; }
    public string Direcc0012 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TmStmp0012 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Clientes0013
{
    public string Client0013 { get; set; }
    public string Nombre0013 { get; set; }
    public string F1Pais00200013 { get; set; }
}
```

**My Custom Model to combine the two table is:**

```
public class ClientModel
{
  public CanaClie0012 CanaClie0012 { get; set; }
  public Clientes0013 Clientes0013 { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    List<ClientModel> lm = new List<ClientModel>();
    ClientModel vm = new ClientModel();
    lm.Add(vm);

    return View(lm);
}
```

**My View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactManager.Models.ClientModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Client00130012
        </th>
        <th>
            F1Pais00200012
        </th>
        <th>
            F1Cana02530012
        </th>
        <th>
            Direcc0012
        </th>
        <th>
            TmStmp0012
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CanaClie0012.Client00130012)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CanaClie0012.F1Pais00200012)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CanaClie0012.F1Cana02530012)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CanaClie0012.Direcc0012)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CanaClie0012.TmStmp0012)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: what is DisplayFor? why not @item.CanaClie0012.Client00130012?

Comment: Try using @Html.LabelFor instead of DisplayFor

Comment: hi @chamara , when i use Html.LabelFor it only shows the fieldname of my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller all you do is instantiate a new ClientModel object and add it to the list. Is that really what is in your index method? If so, the properties would be null and the issue is with your controller not your view. If not, could you post what your index method actually does? Also, in your ClientModel the property is CanaClie0012 so how does CanaClie0012.toList() come into play?

#### Update

I'm not sure how CanaClie0012 and Clientes0013 are related though I am assuming they are given that you are grouping them together within the ClientModel. For the sake of an example lets modify them by adding an id field in CanaClie0012 and a corresponding field in Clientes0013 so that we can join the two classes. Again, I'm only doing this to show what the controller might look like. So now we have the following.

```
public partial class CanaClie0012
{
    public string Id {get; set; }
    public string Client00130012 { get; set; }
    public string F1Pais00200012 { get; set; }
    public string F1Cana02530012 { get; set; }
    public string Direcc0012 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TmStmp0012 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Clientes0013
{
    public string CanaClie0012Id {get; set; }
    public string Client0013 { get; set; }
    public string Nombre0013 { get; set; }
    public string F1Pais00200013 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller might look like.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    using (var context = new MMProdatEntities()) 
    { 
        var lm = from cc in context.CanaClie0012
        join c in context.Clientes0013 on cc.Id equals c.CanaClie0012Id
        select new ClientModel() {
            CanaClie0012 = new CanaClie0012() {
                Client00130012 = cc.Client00130012,
                F1Pais00200012 = cc.F1Pais00200012,
                F1Cana02530012 = cc.F1Cana02530012,
                Direcc0012 = cc.Direcc0012
            },
            Clientes0013 = new Clientes0013() {
                Client0013 = c.Client0013,
                Nombre0013 = c.Nombre0013,
                F1Pais00200013 = c.F1Pais00200013
            }
        };
        return View(lm);
    }

}
```

Heck you do even do the following to confirm the issue is not view related by doing

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    List<ClientModel> lm = new List<ClientModel>();
    ClientModel vm = new ClientModel() 
    {
        CanaClie0012 = new CanaClie0012() 
        {
            Client00130012 = "Client00130012 Data",
            F1Pais00200012 = "F1Pais00200012 data",
            F1Cana02530012 = "F1Cana02530012 data"
        },
        Clientes0013 = new Clientes0013() 
        {
            Client0013 = "Client0013 data",
            Nombre0013 = "Nombre0013 data",
            F1Pais00200013 = "F1Pais00200013 data"
        }
    };
    lm.Add(vm);

    return View(lm);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how my controller should look like? Im having difficulty adding data to my instantiated new ClientModel. What i mean by this "CanaClie0012.toList()" is that when I only use my CanaClie0012 Model instead custom combination view model, i can view all data from my table. of course when I return CanaClie0012.toList(), Im also changing my view structure.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how your data access layer works. You must have some logic that returns you a list/enumberable/iqueryable/ or something instead of simply instantiating a new object. How are you populating your canaClie0012 list?

Comment: This is my DbContext MMProdatEntities db = new MMProdatEntities();

Comment: So then use your context to retrieve whatever data you need

`using (var context = new MMProdatEntities()) { /* some select statement */ }`

Comment: Updated answer based on comments

Comment: Hi i apologize for my ignorant questions. but I think im still missing a cast. Error shows like this: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ContactManager.Models.ClientModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ContactManager.Models.ClientModel'.

Comment: @rcadaoas, you are getting back a dynamic proxy. Try updating `return View(lm)` to `return View(lm.ToList());`

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
    {
         @Html.LabelForModel(item.CanaClie0012.Client00130012)
    }
```

Comment: shows an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It might be a case with your values fetched from database(NULL values).First try to show a single column in your HTML table and make sure this works.